# replace datetime in mysql

Tags: sql, time

after

```
mysql> select now()
```

got

```
2012-03-29 14:07:10
```

if 5 minutes is my interval, so, my question is how to:

change 07 as 05, seconds will be always zero

if i got minute 11, than, it should be replace as 10

Comment: what exactly you want to do .. 
please conform the condition you want to apply ..

if it is 07 then only you want to change to 05 .. ?
if it is 11 then only you want to change to 10..

Comment: @stutiredboy: Please, show us a table with sample data and your expected result

Comment: mm, Thanks all. I means, if 5*x <= current minute < 5*(x+1), then change current minute to 5*x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will round the number of minutes to multiples of 5:

```
select  now() - interval minute(now()) mod 5 minute
```